# Searching a text about story of chasididus

Tags: history, chasidut-hasidism

Somone knows where can I found this text online for free, the whole text or some parts of it:

> Samuel C. Heilman, Who Will Lead Us?: The Story of Five Hasidic Dynasties in America. University of Califronia Press, 2017. עמ' 220-221.

Comment: do you mean free? If not, you can buy the ebook athttps://www.ucpress.edu/ebook/9780520966482/who-will-lead-us

Comment: Yes I mean free @רבות מחשבות

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&hs=URs&ei=n1DjW-bRGeun5wKpmqT4Cg&q=Samuel+C.+Heilman%2C+Who+Will+Lead+Us%3F+pdf&oq=Samuel+C.+Heilman%2C+Who+Will+Lead+Us%3F+pdf&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7640.10580..10895...1.0..0.111.665.5j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i21.9xNpHLB-zBY I cannot vouch for any of the sources being legal or working...

Comment: You get what you pay for.

Comment: Doubtful you’ll find recent publications of universities for free online. [Here’s](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2017/10/hasidism-in-america.html?m=1) some comments about the book though.

Comment: @Oliver thanks. Seems interesting. I discovered the book through Wikipedia about Rashab in Hebrew. He spoke about psychoanalysis in Vienna. Seems very uncommon for an Orthodox rabbi

Comment: Aaah, then have you read The article about Frued and the Rashab? I reckon you’d like it.

Comment: No. Have you a link? @Oliver

Comment: I [have](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/40d3/b307f41e3808c42440ad02c296b17c714f4a.pdf?_ga=2.208921172.770362164.1541660823-1613912748.1541660823). Thank me later.

Comment: great! this is precisely what I looked for @Oliver

Comment: It would be more to your interest as a historian to read the original casenotes in the original German by Wilhelm Steckel. They are free and complete online.

Comment: @Yaacov. Seems very fine. Have you a link

Comment: As memory serves, the PDF original is in Google books or Gutenberg. The title is listed in Maya’s article. You can download it directly. If it is the 5th Lubavitcher Rebbe, it is a testament that even in the face of severe childhood PTSD and child molestation, the victim can overcome the damage and rise to greatness. Understood correctly, it is an inspiration for many similar victims.

Comment: This is the title of the book: Nervose Angstzustande und ihre Behandlung

Comment: Here is a link: https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hws7aa;view=1up;seq=7

Comment: And another link to free, online, multiple copies: http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=Stekel%2C%20Wilhelm%2C%201868%2D1940

Comment: The relevant pages are pp. 160-169

Comment: @kouty See info and links above.